# Does `branch.<name>.merge` represent a remote tracking branch or an upstream branch?

Tags: git

Does `branch.<name>.merge` represent a remote tracking branch or an upstream branch?

1. *Version Control with Git* says

   > But how did Git know to merge those particular branches? The answer
   >   comes from the configuration file:
   >
   > ```
   > [branch "master"]
   >         remote = origin
   >         merge = refs/heads/master
   > ```
   >
   > Paraphrased, this gives Git two key pieces of information: When `master`
   >   is the current, checked out branch, use `origin` as the default remote
   >   from which  to  fetch  updates  during  a  fetch  (or  pull). 
   >   Further,  during  the  merge  step  of git pull, use `refs/heads/master`
   >   from the remote as the default branch to merge into this, the master
   >   branch.

   The quote says "during  the  merge  step  of git pull, use
   `refs/heads/master` from the remote as the default branch to merge
   into this, the master  branch." It seems to me that
   `branch.<name>.merge` represents a remote tracking branch instead of
   an upstream branch.

   But `refs/heads/master` in `merge = refs/heads/master` doesn't look
   like a remote tracking branch (which should look like
   `refs/remotes/<remote>/master`), but a  topic branch, so it seems 
   only an upstream branch to me.
2. The manpage of `git config` says

   > ```
   > branch.<name>.merge
   > ```
   >
   > Defines, together with branch..remote, the upstream branch for
   >   the given branch.

   It seems to say `branch.<name>.merge` represents an upstream branch
   instead of a remote tracking branch.
3. Is it possible that `branch.<name>.merge` implies both a remote
   tracking branch and an upstream branch? I don't think it is
   possible, because a remote tracking branch and its corresponding
   upstream branch(es) can have different basenames, according to how
   `remote.<remote>.fetch` is configured.

Answer (score 1):

In short, `branch.<name>.merge` contains the name of the remote branch on the remote server: it is the upstream branch.

How to convince yourself this is true:

Assuming branch `origin/dev1` exists but not the local `dev1` yet, run this:

```
git checkout dev1
git branch -m dev1 dev2
```

These commands set up `dev1` as having `origin/dev1` as its upstream, then renames it as `dev2`.

The results in my `.git/config` is this:

```
[branch "dev2"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev1
```

Now, `refs/heads/dev1` is something that does not exist anywhere in my sandbox, only on the remote.

Some further clarification of names, based on the discussion in the comments:

**local branch**: `master` or `dev2` are local branches that can get updated from their upstream branch.

**remote-tracking branch**: `origin/master` or `refs/remotes/origin/master` is a pointer stored locally to the state of the remote branch at the time of the last `git fetch` or `git pull`.

**upstream branch**: this is the real remote branch, on the remote server itself, not something local.

Comment: Thanks. If  `branch.<name>.merge` is a remote branch, during the merge step of git pull, how can  `branch.<name>.merge` be used  as the default branch to merge into the current branch? (See the first quote)

Comment: @Tim there's an implicit conversion there: branch `refs/heads/master` on `origin` is locally tracked using `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but that name is not stored in `.git/config`; instead, it's inferred from `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`.

Comment: Is it correct, that a  remote branch and its remote tracking branch can have different basenames? Are they matched according to `remotes.<remote>.fetch`?

Comment: No, but I find the term "remote tracking" often causes confusion. The local branch with an upstream is sometimes (incorrectly) thought as "remote tracking": after all, when I `git pull`, `master` gets `origin/master` merged into it. But it's not remote tracking, it's a local branch with an upstream.
`origin/master` is your real remote-tracking branch, and that one cannot have a different name locally and remotely. The remote-tracking branch for `refs/heads/<branch_name>` on `<remote_name>` is always called `refs/remotes/<remote_name>/<branch_name>`.

Comment: And more confusion to clarify: `<rename_name>/<branch_name>` is the name you would normally use, while `refs/remotes/<remote_name>/<branch_name>` is the plumbing name which is stored in `.git` but not typically used in Git commands. They refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`git config remote.origin.fetch` will show you the "refspec" that maps refnames on the `origin` remote to the local "remote-tracking branch" refs.

The default is

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and it says fetch all the refs on origin that start "refs/heads/" and substitute the `*`'d text in the local rewrite, so `refs/heads/master` the `*` is `master`, and that's what gets subbed in for the `*` in the local ref, the "remote-tracking branch" ref <sup>1</sup>.

The config file specifies which repository a branch's upstream came from and what the refname in that repository is.  When you go to rebase or pull or merge and take the implicit upstream, Git looks at the branch name and the refspec for its source repo, usually `origin`, and figures out what ref that would map to in this repository.

So

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master

[remote "origin"]
        url = git://github.com/git/git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

the local branch `master` tracks `origin`'s branch `master`, and fetching from `origin` maps that branch there to `refs/remotes/origin/master` here, so that's the history rebase and pull and probably some others examine by default to find where or whether the histories have diverged.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The leading `+` just means "don't complain if the fetch abandons history", which is of course exactly how you want fetch to operate when you're simply tracking what's going on with a remote's refs. See the fetch docs for more of its default behavior, e.g. there's times when you want tags fetched, times when you don't</sup>